# How can add in the bootstrap date picker custom text add

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

My date picker is working but I want to add **birthday** text in the input box. please help

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
});
```

```html
<div class="inputField half">
  <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">date_range</i> 
     </span>
  </div>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what do you need, You could simply do something like this(just change the value of input):

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
  $('#datepicker input').val('birthday: ' + $('#datepicker input').val());
});
```

then wrap updating input value in some update-callback if you need etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/re9zpu2g/